# Automapper generic source to known target resolver issue

Tags: c#, generics, automapper, resolver

It's been a while since i've used automapper, but i'm almost sure that my situation should be possible.

**Setup**

I created the following mapping configuration:

```
var map = cfg.CreateMap<TSource, Structure>();
```

So in my situation the source is a generic type (unknown) and the target type is Structure (known).

A possible option for the TSource type could be:

```
public class DataChannel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Ean { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public bool IsManual { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string BuildingId { get; set; }
    }
```

The target Structure object looks like this:

```
public class Structure : IStructure
    {
        public Structure()
        {
            Children = new List<Structure>();
            Properties = new List<StructureProperty>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<StructureProperty> Properties { get; set; }

        public List<Structure> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

**Situation**

For example, I would like the string properties "Unit" and "Type" to be added as a StructureProperty object to the Properties collection of the Structure entity.

```
map.ForMember(c => c.Properties, m => m.MapFrom<StructurePropertyResolver<TSource>>());
```

How can this be done?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html

Comment: yea, but I don't know the source type upfront.

Comment: Exactly as in that example.